# Plot background and labels in the same graph-matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot background and data labels in the same graph. I wrote folowing which gives two seperate plots. Any help to put them together?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import plot,axis,show,pcolor,colorbar,bone

data = np.random.rand(4,4)
pcolor(data)
colorbar()


axiss = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0), (2, 2), (0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 0), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
x,y = zip(*axiss)


labels = ['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'u4',
         'u5', 'u6', 'u7', 'u8',
         'u9', 'u10']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y)
for i, txt in enumerate(labels):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i],y[i]))
show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reverse the order of things such that the first few lines are:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = np.random.rand(4,4)
pcolor(data)
colorbar()
```

basically, this way the `pcolor` is plotted in `ax` and the annotations are also on `ax`.

[image]